# MDX: Combining output for different criteria

Tags: ssas, mdx

I am new to MDX queries, and working in SSAS. I have two queries that are working suitably, but I want their output combined in a single result. The two queries differ in the cities selected by their where clauses, but they both come from the same cube and use the same measure.

**A_to_B**: Supplier city A to Consumer city B

```
SELECT { [Measures].[Quantity - Transactions] } ON COLUMNS,
       { [Tb Product].[Name].[Name].ALLMEMBERS } ON ROWS
FROM [Cube]
WHERE ([Tb Supplier].[City].&[A],
       [Tb Consumer].[City].&[B])
```

**B_to_A**: Supplier city B to Consumer city A

```
SELECT { [Measures].[Quantity - Transactions] } ON COLUMNS,
       { [Tb Product].[Name].[Name].ALLMEMBERS } ON ROWS
FROM [Cube]
WHERE ([Tb Supplier].[City].&[B],
       [Tb Consumer].[City].&[A])
```

Is there a way for the output of these queries to be produced side-by-side by Product, like this? In SQL I would have used a FULL OUTER JOIN, but I can't figure out the equivalent in MDX.

```
|          | A_to_B | B_to_A |
| ProductA |     10 |      2 |
| ProductB |    100 |      0 |
| ProductC |      0 |     99 |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply move you Where statements to columns:

```
Select
{[Measures].[Quantity - Transactions]} *
{
    ([Tb Supplier].[City].&[B], [Tb Consumer].[City].&[A]),
    ([Tb Supplier].[City].&[A], [Tb Consumer].[City].&[B])
} on 0,
{[Tb Product].[Name].[Name].AllMembers} on 1
From [Cube]
```

You may create calculated members in order to unite two tuples:

```
With 

Member [Tb Supplier].[City].[B2A] as
Aggregate([Tb Supplier].[City].&[B], [Tb Consumer].[City].&[A])

Member [Tb Supplier].[City].[A2B] as
Aggregate([Tb Supplier].[City].&[A], [Tb Consumer].[City].&[B])

Select 
    {[Tb Supplier].[City].[A2B],[Tb Supplier].[City].[B2A]} on 0
From [Cube]
Where ([Measures].[Quantity - Transactions])
```

Comment: would it be tidier if you also move `[Measures].[Quantity - Transactions]` to the WHERE clause?

Comment: Perfection knows no limits. ;)

Comment: Not really, there is no the Where clause. :)

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to create the headers, A_to_B and B_to_A?

Comment: Sure, added to my answer.

Comment: I can't say how much this helped me out. My final query included an additional member that used Iif(IsEmpty()) to take care of the zeros. Would it be appropriate for me to post that as an answer? This is my first question, so I am unsure.

Comment: Yeah, that's the point to be able to answer your own questions. The more answers the better. But bear in mind that your answer must be related to the initial question. If you didn't ask about dealing with zeros and answered it, you would make it irrelevant. You may create a separate question and answer yourself, it's okay.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this script and it throws an exception:

```
SELECT 
    {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]}
  * 
    {
      {[Geography].[Geography].[Country].&[United States] * [Product].[Category].&[1]}
     ,{[Geography].[Geography].[Country].&[France] * [Product].[Category].&[3]}
    } ON 0
 ,{[Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20070801]} ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

This message:

> Query (5, 7) The  function expects a tuple set expression for the 1
>   argument. A string or numeric expression was used.

This is because you need to make either side of the cross-join specifically a set - without extra brackets it does not know this and throws an exception.

So this is the "perfect" version of the script:

```
SELECT 
    {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]}
  * 
    {
      {[Geography].[Geography].[Country].&[United States]} * {[Product].[Category].&[1]}
     ,{[Geography].[Geography].[Country].&[France]} * {[Product].[Category].&[3]}
    } ON 0
 ,{[Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20070801]} ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

I'd prefer to move the measure to the WHERE clause and also get rid of some of the redundant braces:

```
SELECT 
  {
      {[Geography].[Geography].[Country].&[United States]}
    * 
      {[Product].[Category].&[1]}
   ,
      {[Geography].[Geography].[Country].&[France]}
    * 
      {[Product].[Category].&[3]}
  } ON 0
 ,[Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20070801] ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE 
  [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount];
```

Translated to your cube:

```
SELECT 
  {
    {[Tb Supplier].[City].&[B]} * {[Tb Consumer].[City].&[A]}
   ,
    {[Tb Supplier].[City].&[A]} * {[Tb Consumer].[City].&[B]}
  } ON 0
 ,[Tb Product].[Name].[Name].ALLMEMBERS ON 1
FROM [Cube]
WHERE 
  [Measures].[Quantity - Transactions];
```

Comment: Ah, right, thanks for your correction! I've updated my answer. Also you may use no *: {([D1],[H1].[M1], [D2],[H2].[M2]),([D1],[H1].[M2], [D2],[H2].[M1])}.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the others, here is one that replaces nulls with zeros in the output.

```
With 

Member [Tb Supplier].[City].[B2A] as
Aggregate([Tb Supplier].[City].&[B], [Tb Consumer].[City].&[A])

Member [Tb Supplier].[City].[A2B] as
Aggregate([Tb Supplier].[City].&[A], [Tb Consumer].[City].&[B])

Member [Measures].[Quantity_Transactions] as
    Iif( IsEmpty( [Measures].[Quantity - Transactions] ), 
    0, 
    [Measures].[Quantity - Transactions] )

SELECT 
    { [Measures].[Quantity_Transactions] } *
    { [Tb Supplier].[City].[B2A], 
      [Tb Supplier].[City].[A2B] } on COLUMNS
    , [Tb Product].[Name].[Name].ALLMEMBERS ON ROWS
FROM [Cube]
```